# Unable to remove SOME map Markers in a retained mapfragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm coding a simple Android activity, one google map "retained" mapfragment, two button ("add marker" "remove marker"), plus a "data" fragment for retaining data chunks through the activity life cycle.
The "add marker" calls a method that place a fixed `testMarker` plus calls the  google location service and place a marker on the "getlastlocation" position (you'll see the code anyway). 
"remove marker"....remove the markers.
How it behaves:

- 1. first time load "add" and "remove" do their job, regardless how
     many times you use them
- 2. adding the markers, changing orientation (with the life cycle
     involved), and  removing them, work as a charm
- 3. (THE PROBLEM) with the new orientation "add" add both marker, but "remove" **remove only the test one.**

I'll post the basic code that gives me this problem, I've tried more convoluted things (like using a `messageHandler` to handle the google service response, retaining the instance of googlemap through the "data" fragment" etc) with exactly the same result so I guess there is no reason to bother you with them.

My feeling is that I'm missing something about the activity life cycle, but I'm getting desperate to know what!

By the way this is my first question, out of desperation :-), so if you find it horribly written, please, help me to improve it!

```
public class RetainMapDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
private static final String TOGGLE = "toggle";
private static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

protected GoogleMap mMap;
protected Marker testMarker;
protected Marker mLocationMarker;
protected Location mLocation;
private TrackFragment trackFragment;
private Button addMarkerButton;
private Button removeMarkerButton;
private boolean buttonToggle = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(TOGGLE)) {
            buttonToggle = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(TOGGLE);
        }
    }
    addMarkerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addMarker);
    removeMarkerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removeMarker);
    addMarkerButton.setEnabled(buttonToggle);
    removeMarkerButton.setEnabled(!buttonToggle);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // First incarnation of this activity.
        mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);

    }
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    trackFragment = (TrackFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("data");

    // create the fragment and data the first time
    if (trackFragment == null) {
        // add the fragment
        trackFragment = new TrackFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(trackFragment, "data").commit();


    }
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();

    }

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    testMarker = trackFragment.getTestMarker();
    mLocationMarker = trackFragment.getmLocationMarker();


}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    trackFragment.setTestMarker(testMarker);
    trackFragment.setmLocationMarker(mLocationMarker);

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}


public void addMarker(View view) {
    testMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(43, 9)).title("Test Marker"));

    buttonToggle = false;
    addMarkerButton.setEnabled(buttonToggle);
    removeMarkerButton.setEnabled(!buttonToggle);
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

public void removeMarker(View view) {
    testMarker.remove();
    mLocationMarker.remove();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    buttonToggle = true;
    addMarkerButton.setEnabled(buttonToggle);
    removeMarkerButton.setEnabled(!buttonToggle);
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(TOGGLE, buttonToggle);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    mLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(),mLocation.getLongitude())).title("My location"));

    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry I've actually forgot to specify that "remove marker" does also disconnect the google location service, you can see it in the code but maybe it was better to make that clear...

Comment: Ehhh just another thing.... you may notice that my activity class implements things like LocationListener but you don't see the "override"-s... there is just a bunch of empty "override" method on the bottom of the code, but sure enough they don't affect the code behaviour so I cut them to make it short

Comment: Can you explain this line "(THE PROBLEM) with the new orientation "add" add both marker, but "remove" remove only the test one." Do you mean
you're having problem when the screen orientation is changed?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer and thx for your attention, first of all.

Comment: Yes after an orientation change the Button that add the 2 markers add them to the map without problem but the Button that (should) remove them remove only the test one and not the other.